# Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:4200/favicon.ico ("default-src")

Tags: angular

I just update angular to angular-cli@10.0.8 (with `npm update` to update all the project) and since when I launch  `ng serve` the web page display Cannot GET /.
And the only thing the console print is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVjfE.png)

I cannot find anything to fix it...

**EDIT**

> chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.06 kB [initial] [rendered]
> chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 707 bytes
> [initial] [rendered] chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map
> (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered] chunk {styles} styles.js,
> styles.js.map (styles) 686 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {vendor}
> vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 341 kB [initial] [rendered] Date:
> 2020-08-29T14:32:50.233Z - Hash: 0a65679c378d775ba62b - Time: 4787ms
>
> ERROR in src/app/creations/creations.component.ts:4:32 - error TS2732:
> Cannot find module 'src/data/game.json'. Consider using
> '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension
>
> 4 import * as creationsData from "src/data/game.json";
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ src/app/creations/creations.component.ts:25:21 - error TS2339:
> Property 'games' does not exist on type 'JSON'.
>
> 25     let temp = data.games;
> ~~~~~
>
> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

This is the content of the console log on `ng serve` (the error was here before the crash).

Comment: can you check your console for errors (where you launched ng serve)?

Comment: I actually recreate an empty project with the latest version of all modules and it works. I search a reason why the first crash on the update. If you have any clue to help me I keep this subject open for the moment.